# Indoor localiztion

Tags: android, android-maps

I am creating the indoor localisation using beacons on Android OS. I would like to display the map of the building and draw my position on the map. Do I need to use the MapView or ImageView and draw point position?

Comment: MapView will only work for you if Google has a map of your building.  If they don't have that data, you'll need to roll your own.

Comment: If that's your biggest challenge then I'm impressed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a MapView with Tile Overlays and a very high level of zoom. You can find more details by the following [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/tileoverlay).

Comment: why my png map is repeated? how to display one tile